# Unable to create partial indexes using bloom

Tags: postgresql, index, index-tuning

I'm new to bloom indexes and currently my table has 3 partial indexes for the same column in the `WHERE` clause and with different column combinations for the same table. I was trying to replace them all with 1 bloom index.

However, when I create a bloom index with `WHERE` clause using below syntax, I get below error:

```
CREATE EXTENSION bloom;

CREATE INDEX idx_bloom_bar ON message USING bloom  
(s, p, c, m, e, id) 
WHERE (islatest = true)
WITH (length=56, col1=4, col2=4, col3=4, col4=4, col5=4, col6=4);
```

> ```
> SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "WITH"
> Position: 165
> ```

However, without `WHERE` clause, I'm able to create this index successfully.

Please let me know if we can use them as a replacement of multiple partial indexes or not to reduce number of indexes on my table.

Comment: jjanes clarified the syntax error. I am not convinced that the bloom index beats your current indexing, though. Can you provide your previous indexes and table definition, and rough details of write patterns and relevant cardinalities?

Comment: Thanks @ErwinBrandstetter , I can't provide those details here. However, I'm further working on performance analysis/observing changes into the query execution time (after  replacing old indexes with bloom) - will share details regarding increase/decrease into overall query execution timings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WITH clause comes before the WHERE clause in the [CREATE INDEX syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html).  You are not free to rearrange the order as you have attempted here.

This ordering is a little unintuitive to me, but that is how it works.